# Understanding the proof of $\pi(x)\ge \log(\log x), x\ge 2$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

Here $\pi(x)=$ number of primes which are less or equal to $x$.

Let $p_n$ denote the $n$th prime. Then since any prime dividing $p_1...p_n+1$ is distinct from $p_1,...,p_n$; it follows that $p_{n+ I}\le p_1...p_n + 1$.

By induction, $p_n\le 2^{2^n}$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$. It follows that $\pi(2^{2^n})\ge n$.

For $x > e$, choose an integer $n$ so that $e^{e^{n-1}}\lt x\le e^{e^n}$.

---

*I understand that this can be done as follows: $x\gt e\implies \log(\log x)>0$ so we can just take $n=\lfloor \log(\log x)\rfloor$. This gives: $n-1\lt \log(\log(x))\le n,$ whence the result follows.*

---

$\color{blue}{\text{If $n > 3$, then $e^{n - 1} > 2^n$}}$ so that $$
\pi(x)\ge \pi(e^{e^{n-1}})\ge \pi(e^{2^n} )\ge  \pi (2^{2^n} )\ge n \ge \log (\log x) \tag 1$$
This proves the result for $x > e^e$. If $x \le e^e$ the inequality is obvious.

I don't understand the second inequality in $(1)$:

$(i)$ it is true only for $n>3$ as the blue color statement is true for $n>3$.

$(ii)$ From $(i)$, $(1)$ is proved for $n>3$. This means that one should consider the statements separately for the cases when $n=1,n=2,n=3$. This means the cases $1\lt x\le e^e, e^{e}\lt x\le e^{e^2}, e^{e^2}\lt x\le e^{e^3}$ respectively. But these cases have not been considered. Is my understanding correct?

Can anyone please help me understand that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(ii) You are correct, however the bits that have been left out are pretty easy.  For example take $n=3$.  Then
$$e^{e^2}<x\le e^{e^3}\quad\Rightarrow\quad \log\log x\le 3\ .$$
So it is sufficient to prove that $\pi(x)\ge3$, which means that there are at least $3$ primes less than or equal to $x$, and this is true because $x>e^{e^2}>2^{2^2}>5$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Alternatively, we first prove that for $x\gt e^{e^3}, \pi(x)\ge \log\log x$ (the proof in my post goes through). For $2\le x\le e^{e^3},$ we proceed by contradiction:  suppose on the contrary that there is some x such that $\pi(x)<\log\log x\implies \pi(x)<3\implies \pi(x)=1$ or $\pi(x)=2$. If $\pi(x)=1$ then $x\in [2,3)$. So $\log \log x\lt \log(\log 3)\le 1$ hence $\pi(x)\ge \log(\log x)$ which is not possible. So $\pi(x)=2$. It follows that $x\in [3,5)$, whence $\log (\log x)\le \log\log 5\le 2=\pi(x)$ which is also not possible. This is a contradiction.